# Hot Chocolate GraphQL SyntaxNode

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

In the Hot Chocolate GraphQL, OnError method, i can see(in VS watch during debug) the SyntaxNode which show me the request body.how i get it value. because it is not available in IError.  how i can get the value showing at SyntaxNode

[image]